# lldb: ImportError: No module named site

Tags: xcode, macos, xcode6, lldb

I am on Mac Yosemite, with a brand new install of XCode 6.3 with command line utilities.

lldb works fine trough XCode, I wanted to try and use lldb via the terminal, but when I type the lldb command I get:

```
a-MacBook-Air:K&R a$ lldb
ImportError: No module named site
```

I don't know if this is of any help:

```
a-MacBook-Air:K&R a$ which lldb
/usr/bin/lldb
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it.

I installed canopy(https://www.enthought.com/products/canopy/) before. Canopy prepare python environment. This python environment was disturbing using lldb.

If you are using canopy, You should uninstall it or change canopy setting.
From Canopy title menu ==> Preferences ==> General ==> "Default Python Environment" and Press "Unset as default". Now you can use lldb.

(I'm using Canopy 1.5.2)

Cheers,

Kimiaki

Comment: Thank you. I have Canopy installed, but I still wish to keep that as the default python environment. How do I accomplish that?

Comment: Launch as `PATH=/usr/bin:${PATH} lldb`

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be caused by Enthought Canopy, as explained in the answer by Fujiwara.

If you do not wish to change settings system-wide, just temporarily modify your `PATH` as you launch LLDB:

```
> PATH=/usr/bin:${PATH} lldb
```

Comment: Yes ! it really helps me !